# How to find only first and last numeric characters in string

Tags: c#, regex

How to find only first and last numeric characters in string?

> For example:  string a = 1234  find result: 14, but not 1234 or 23

It used for formatting string. And loaded from file. So only regular expressions

Loaded regular expression parser:

```
Match resultMatch = new Regex(regex).Match(sourceString);
        return resultMatch.Success ? resultMatch.Value : null;
```

Comment: The first is a[0] and last is a[a.Length - 1].

Comment: Ok, [mcve]! We need some input, just one exemple to show basic logic is not an exemple input. Then we need what you have try: Do you have any code? Because it's rather really simple or really unclear..

Comment: Simple google-search: get first element in list + get last element in list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP is trying to find the first and last _alphanumeric_ character

Comment: And if regEx is really needed this is a funny looking one: `(.).*(.)`. As you say Alphanumeric and show an exemple with only number, as you didnt mention if punctuation or space is important. I m assuming that none of these is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, only numeric strings are needed. Not regular expression not working for me. It used for formatting string and loaded from file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C# well, so here is some more or less pseudo code:

```
char first;
char last;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] matches "[A-Za-z0-9]")
    {
        first = a[i];
        break;
    }
}

int j;
for (j = a.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
{
    if (a[j] matches "[A-Za-z0-9]")
    {
        last = a[j];
        break;
    }
}

return first + last;
```